# Trying to create $now folder and copy .sql files created folders

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, debian

I have a shell script that I am trying to run every few days that copies .sql database files and moves them into a designated folder appeneded with /$now/. The script executes perfectly, but I am getting a cp: cannot create regular file '/path/to/dir/$now/': No such file or directory.

I know these folders exist because it is showing up when I 'ls -ltr' the directory.

All of my permissions are executable and writable.This has been puzzling me for about a week now and I just cant put a finger on it.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUP_DIR="/backups/mysql/"
FILE_DIR=/dbase/files/
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")

# setting the input field seperator to newline
IFS=$'\n'

# find db backups and loop over
for file in $(find ${FILE_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -name "*.sql" -type f -exec basename {} \;); do
    # create backup directory:
    mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}"

    # copy file over        
    cp "${FILE_DIR}${file}" "${BACUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}/"
done
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

Error I am getting:

```
+ mkdir -pv /backups/mysql/health/2014_12_04
+ cp /dbase/files/health.sql health/2014_12_04/
cp: cannot create regular file 'health/2014_12_04/': No such file or directory
```

This is happening for all 9 directories already created

Comment: What's the snippet of code around that line? (Include the assignment lines for any relevant variables.)

Comment: I have added the code to the original question.

Comment: If you add `-v` to that `mkdir` line do you see it output that it is creating the directory? Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see what that shows you is being run when it fails.

Comment: Ok so when I add the -v it tells me it cannot access the *.sql: no such file or directory. I took the .sql off of the wildcard and now it just creates a file out of every .txt or .isi and puts a sub-directory with the date inside those. No files are copied into the $now directory.

Comment: I have it creating the directories now, but there is still no .sql files being copied over into the $now directory. No such file or directory; Even though it lists that it created the directory.

Comment: That error may be about the source as well as the destination of the `cp`. What does `set -x` say is happening when it fails? Does the source exist?

Comment: Where do I need to place set -x in the file? I think I may have it in the wrong place.

Comment: Before the lines you want to have it be in effect for. In this case anywhere above the loop.

Comment: The out i am getting looks like this:
    + mkdir -pv /path/to/sql/$now
    +cp /path/to/sql/file.sql backup/$now/
    cp: cannot creat regular file 'backup/$now/': No such file or directory

Comment: Put the output in the post so you can format it and please don't edit the output. That output cannot be what you are actually getting unless the script in the post isn't the script you are actually running.

Comment: See below for output error

Comment: I moved the error to the post from your answer. You should delete the answer as it isn't an answer.

Comment: If that is the error you are getting then the snippet in your post is **not** the script you are running and the script you are running either doesn't have `${BACKUP_DIR}` in the second argument to `cp` or it has a typo in the variable name. Notice how `/backups/mysql/` is missing from that argument?

Comment: There was a typo. I fat fingered something. See the answer below. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a typo. I was missing the 'K' in $BACKUP_DIR on the cp line. Here is the correct code:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUP_DIR="/backups/mysql/"
FILE_DIR=/dbase/files/
now=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")

# setting the input field seperator to newline
IFS=$'\n'

# find db backups and loop over
for file in $(find ${FILE_DIR} -maxdepth 1 -name "*.sql" -type f -exec basename {} \;); do
    # create backup directory:
    mkdir -p "${BACKUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}"

    # copy file over        
    cp "${FILE_DIR}${file}" "${BACKUP_DIR}${file%.sql}/${now}/"
done
```